# Does a sorted dataframe keep its order after groupby?

Tags: pandas, sorting, group-by

I would like to keep the latest entry per group in a dataframe:

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd    
data = [
    ['A', date(2018,2,1), "I want this"],
    ['A', date(2018,1,1), "Don't want"],
    ['B', date(2019,4,1), "Don't want"],
    ['B', date(2019,5,1), "I want this"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'date', 'result'])
```

The following does what I want (found and credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57550922/1864294)):

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('name').tail(1)
```

```
    name    date    result
0   A   2018-02-01  I want this
3   B   2019-05-01  I want this
```

But how do I know the order is always preserved when you do a `groupby` on a sorted data frame like `df`? Is it somewhere documented?

Comment: Please explain better your expected output

Comment: The function does exactly what I need. I just wonder how I can be sure that the order is preserved in all edge cases?

Comment: You want to preserve the order by dates as per the original dataframe?

Comment: `groupby('name', sort=False)`?

Comment: But I think you can just do `df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')`, which is faster than groupby.

Comment: @QuangHoang That's a brilliant idea. This is not only more efficient but also more readable. Would you mind adding this solution as an answer?

Comment: Thanks, but the actual question (does groupby preserve the order of the original dataframe) is not answered by the linked answer/question, isn't it?

Comment: 1) Yes, `groupby()` will preserve data order *within each group*. 2) `groupby` with `sort=True` sorts the groups by (group) keys. If you pass `sort=False`, the keys are returned as ordered in the data. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: It does, yes. Thanks! But this means the answer by @mozway is not quite right?

Answer (score 2):

No it won't. Try to replace A with Z to see it.

Use `sort=False`:

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('name', sort=False).tail(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  And indeed, the documentation says: "Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group." Probably a short  "...for `sort=False`" added would make the more clear.

Comment: @Michael that's a bit different. `sort` controls the order of the group keys. The doc describes the behavior if the indices within a group ;)

Comment: But if it only affects the sorting of indices/keys why do I need it then? Then all I need to know is in the documentation already (I just was too dumb to see it): `Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.`